# Transferring a search request from my website to another website and get response

Tags: php

[lughat_urdu](http://udb.gov.pk/) this is a dictionary of Urdu language.
I'm making a website which take an input from the user and search the meaning of that word on this website server. If the meaning of that is found it return the meaning of the word, else return not available. Without redirect to the official website.
Below is my code which I try:

```
<form method="POST">
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control"  placeholder="student name..." >
  </div>
  <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $curl=curl_init('http://udb.gov.pk/');
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POST,1);
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'searchterm='.$_POST['name']);
    $result=curl_exec($curl);
    echo $result;
}
?>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. You say “Google” (maybe that word is synonymous with “search” for you?), you link to a Pakistan government site, and your code references a third site. Further, “not working” is never helpful. Please explain the intended use better, what you expect for a result, and any error messages you are receiving (with full PHP error reporting turned on). Also, because this is HTTP, make sure you inspect the status codes from servers.

Comment: okay sorry for my english i will edit it